# What is 1 Gbps RJ45/SFP Combination WAN Ports?

Tags: router

I am looking at router https://www.ubnt.com/unifi-routing/unifi-security-gateway-pro-4/. And it mentions the "combination port" which has the line drawn connecting the pair together. Can someone explain to me what is it? Am I meant to use one or another or I can utilize all 6 ports doing different thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's two physical ports, a RJ45 copper Ethernet port and an SFP slot for modules/transceivers (e.g. optical fiber).

"Combination" means that you can only have *one* of them active (either copper or SFP), **but not both at the same time**. They both have the same port number, and the configuration screen shows them as one port.

Usually, if a SFP module is inserted then the port is in SFP mode. If there's no module, then it's in RJ45 mode.

(I guess this saves on manufacturing cost by not requiring as large a switch chip as otherwise?)

---

SFP is "Small form factor pluggable", a popular type of 1 Gbps communication module slot – usually optical transceivers, but other kinds exist. If it *wasn't* a combo port, you could have bought a RJ45 SFP module and used it for standard twisted-pair copper Ethernet, getting an extra port that way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Also if I may ask, why router need to differentiate between WAN and LAN port? Isn't these port just an interface with IP assigned? Can I use WAN port as LAN port by statically assign the IP?

Comment: @Zanko: *Usually* it's just a matter of what default configuration gets applied to those ports, nothing else. Though I cannot speak for the USG specifically; it's very possible that its firewall config and settings screen make strong assumptions about which way connections go. At least my earlier search online for the user guide PDF led me to believe that the GUI isn't very flexible in that regard, and you'd need CLI to configure it differently.

Comment: I see, also it seems from PDF datasheet `The USG-PRO-4 WAN port, as a result of being a combination SFP/GigE port, is a
pure 1 Gbps port`. Does this also mean my SFP is limited to 1 Gbps too?

Comment: Yes. You'd need SFP+ for 10 Gbps modules, XSFP etc. for even higher rates. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver for all the distinctions between them.

Comment: so I assume the advantage is purely distance?

Comment: Advantage of optical fiber over twisted-pair? Yes, _especially_ when trying to do 10 Gbps and higher – SM fiber can go for tens of miles, Cat6 tens of meters. Also resistance to EM interference.